# Rails_admin routes not appearing

Tags: rails-admin

I have several plugins that extend rails_admin but these actions do not appear in my routes

```
Routes for RailsAdmin::Engine:
dashboard GET           /                                      rails_admin/main#dashboard
index GET|POST          /:model_name(.:format)                 rails_admin/main#index
new GET|POST            /:model_name/new(.:format)             rails_admin/main#new
export GET|POST         /:model_name/export(.:format)          rails_admin/main#export
bulk_delete POST|DELETE /:model_name/bulk_delete(.:format)     rails_admin/main#bulk_delete
history_index GET       /:model_name/history(.:format)         rails_admin/main#history_index
bulk_action POST        /:model_name/bulk_action(.:format)     rails_admin/main#bulk_action
show GET                /:model_name/:id(.:format)             rails_admin/main#show
edit GET|PUT            /:model_name/:id/edit(.:format)        rails_admin/main#edit
delete GET|DELETE       /:model_name/:id/delete(.:format)      rails_admin/main#delete
history_show GET        /:model_name/:id/history(.:format)     rails_admin/main#history_show
show_in_app GET         /:model_name/:id/show_in_app(.:format) rails_admin/main#show_in_app
```

Why?

[Source](https://github.com/adamwong246/StEnki)

Comment: What do you mean plugins? rails admin actions?
Can you show an example of one of these plugins?